# BEFORE TRIGGER not updating value postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I am trying to implement a `BEFORE` trigger, which updates a field to current date if another field is updated. Even though the updated value gets assigned to `NEW.zuletzt`, whenever I call `Select * from hoert`, I still see the older `zuletzt` value. Here is the trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION changedAnzhoert() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    currDate DATE:=CURRENT_DATE;
BEGIN 
    IF OLD.anzahl<NEW.anzahl THEN
        NEW.zuletzt:=currDate;
        raise notice 'Neues Datum: %', NEW.zuletzt;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trhoertChange BEFORE UPDATE ON hoert
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changedAnzhoert();
```

When I run:

```
UPDATE hoert SET anzahl=anzahl+1 WHERE id=1;
```

I see:

> NOTICE: Neues Datum: 2019-01-03 
>   UPDATE 1

Comment: Please show us the UPDATE statement you use.

Comment: UPDATE hoert SET anzahl=anzahl+1 WHERE id=1
NOTICE:  Neues Datum: 2019-01-03
UPDATE 1

Comment: Maybe you are not committing your UPDATE?

Comment: Hmm weird, I did try it as a Transaction with BEGIN; UPDATE; COMMIT; , still no change in the table (except anzahl=anzahl+1)

Comment: In psql execute `\d hoert` and check whether the trigger is the only one.

Comment: @klin that was it, the trigger was initially saved as AFTER trigger for some reason. NEW cannot be updated on AFTER triggers. Thank You! Write this as answer so I can chose this as Answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you have another trigger. In psql execute

```
\d hoert
```

and check whether the trigger is the only one.